# Trouble understanding syntax in C code for masking and bit conversion

Tags: c, binary, masking

Below is a code which returns the signed value of the last 6 bits in an 8 bit binary value however I am struggling to understand how the code does this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I understand that `(b&0x20)` returns the last 6 bits however the `? b` afterwards and hence the subsequent code has me a little confused.

```
return (b & 0x20) ? b | ~0x3F : b & 0x3F;
```

Comment: "returns the signed value of the last 6 bits in an 8 bit binary value" --> `b | ~0x3F` can return more than the last (least significant) 6 bits. "(b&0x20) returns the last 6 bits" --> not quite.  It returns the value of the 1 bit as 0x20 or 0x00.  `b & 0x3F` returns the least 6 bits.  As is, nothing limits `b` to an 8 bit binary value.  Better to see the function return type and the declaration of `b`.

Comment: If bit 6 is set, set all higher bits, otherwise remove all higher bits. It sign extends a 6-bit value to a larger integer type (which is impossible to determine given the code, because it depends on the type of `b`).

Comment: @PaulHankin Good insight.  Note: `b | ~0x3F` is at least `int`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica yes, but `unsigned int` is also possible (as well as larger types).

Comment: Sorry my bad, b is of type unsigned char. I am just a bit lost as to how the code works in terms of its logic.

Comment: actually, figured it out by doing a few examples myself. thanks guys , you lot helped :)

Comment: why simply do not use bitfileds and forget about the implementation: https://godbolt.org/z/a8KWKrW77 Lets compiler do the hard work :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is probably written for circumstances in which:

- `b` is an `int` or narrower.
- Two’s complement is used to represent negative numbers.

The `?` and `:` form a conditional operation. Generally, in `X ? Y : Z`, `X` is tested. If `X` is not zero, `Y` is evaluated and used as the result of the expression. If `X` is zero, `Z` is evaluated and used as the result.

So, in `(b & 0x20) ? b | ~0x3F : b & 0x3F`, `(b & 0x20)` is tested. `b & 0x20` isolates from `b` the single bit in `0x20`, so this is testing whether the bit in that position is on.

Let’s consider the “off” result first, when `b & 0x3F` is used. `0x3F` is an `int` value with the low six bits set to 1 and all higher bits set to 0. When this is ANDed with `b`, in `b & 0x3F`, the result is the low six bits of `b`, with all higher bits set to 0. As an `int`, this result has the value of the low six bits of `b`.

For the “on” result, `b | ~0x3F` is used. The `~` operator flips each bit. Since `0x3F` has the low six bits set to 1 and all higher bits set to 0, `~0x3F` has the low six bits set to 0 and all higher bits set to 1. When that is ORed with `b`, in `b | ~0x3F`, the result is the low six bits of `b` with all higher bits set to 1.

What this does is “sign extend” the low six bits of `b`: If the bit in position 5 (`0x20`) is clear, the result of `(b & 0x20) ? b | ~0x3F : b & 0x3F` is the low six bits of `b` with all higher bits cleared. If the bit in position 5 is set, the result is the low six bits of `b` with all higher bits set. So the effect is the bit in position 5 is copied to all higher bits.

When two’s complement is used, extending the sign bit of narrower type yields the same value in a wider type.

For example, in three-bit two’s complement:

- 011 represents 3.
- 010 represents 2.
- 001 represents 1.
- 000 represents 0.
- 111 represents −1.
- 110 represents −2.
- 101 represents −3.
- 100 represents −4.

When we sign-extend those to 5 bits, we have:

- 00011 represents 3.
- 00010 represents 2.
- 00001 represents 1.
- 00000 represents 0.
- 11111 represents −1.
- 11110 represents −2.
- 11101 represents −3.
- 11100 represents −4.

A five-bit integer has other bit patterns, of course, but those are the ones we get by sign-extending from a three-bit integer.

Comment: A much easier way is to use bitfields and leave the hard work for the compiler: https://godbolt.org/z/a8KWKrW77

Comment: Compiler is better than tricology: https://godbolt.org/z/K6svWdzv3

Comment: @0___________: The behavior of converting an out-of-range value to a signed integer is implementation-defined.